# Image3D interactive manipulation slower in 10.4.1?

Tags: front-end, image3d

I've upgraded to MMa version 10.4.1 under MacOS 10.11.4 on a MBP Retina. We use `Image3D` a lot in our work and it *seems* like it has gotten very very slow in this update. Indeed the whole MacOS UI will 'seize' (cursor disappears, machine is non-responsive) if I do things like change an expression that renders an `Image3D`, leading to its 'deactivation' in the notebook.

In the past, I've been able to interactively rotate, plane-cut, etc things like this

```
Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"]
```

pretty easily. It's not 'speedy' by any means, but certainly not as bad as I feel like it is now.

Has anyone else experienced this phenomena?

(NB- this is on a relatively 'clean' MacOS install, graphics card / energy saving set to use the nvidia card, etc.)

**Edit** -- I put a notebook with a very simple volume of 16^3 of a sphere, on Dropbox here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19616/painfulrotation.nb

This was very responsive in the past.

Comment: [This](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/817719) maybe related.

Comment: Do you have an example that was relatively speedy and is now noticeably slow? The given example seems to always have been quite slow.

Comment: Ill dig one up that is simple. Most of our stuff is result of a bunch of otherwise annoying computations :)

Comment: Do you see any improvement with `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 "RenderingOptions" -> {"HardwareAntialiasingQuality" -> 0.}]` ?

Comment: @StefanR I put a DB link w/ a super simple rendered volume that, before, was very responsive.

Comment: @ilian It makes it  'better', not great but better. It doesn't lock up at start of rotation, for example.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please also provide the exact model/generation of your MBP and its NVidia card?

Comment: @ilian I'm having the same problem with both 10.4 and 10.4.1 on late 2013 15 inch retina Macbook Pro with NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB graphics card.

Comment: @ilian Mid 2012 MBP NVIDIA 650M (1024mb), 16gb RAM, 2.7ghz cpu

Comment: @ilian - these are my last few months with this particular model as I'm getting a replacement at the end of the semester. I'm happy to hold on to it a little bit for testing things like this if you'd like. (BTW- what happened to the pre-release/beta program? I'd hate to have to go back to using internal builds :)

Comment: @xslittlegrass- indeed I bet it is. I sure wish there was some sort of 'cross-site' communication between SX and Wolfram Community. I miss a lot when I only have time to search one...